# Don't allow users to SSH to other systems

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

I know how to restrict SSH access to a system. How can I restrict SSH access to ANOTHER system when a user has logged in to my system. For example:

```
# ssh joe@myserver
# joe@myserver $ /home/joe
# joe@myserver $ /home/joe ssh joe@anotherserver
# BLOCK THIS ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm looking at IPTables now but I'm not sure of the implications of blocking outgoing port 22.

Comment: If the user don't have admin right, maybe restrict the ssh command into the /usr/sbin ? So only those with sudo access can ssh out?

Comment: Similar questions : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472554/block-outgoing-ssh-connection-from-server   https://serverfault.com/questions/660880/restricting-per-user-outgoing-ssh

Comment: @Darius presumably the user could provide their own ssh program

Comment: The [Server Fault link](https://serverfault.com/questions/660880/restricting-per-user-outgoing-ssh) that @ChristopherHostage provided seems to be exactly what you want/need; if cross-site "duplicates" were permissible flags, I'd be flagging this question as a dupe of it.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - We could simply migrate it, that way, the duplicate could be flagged.

Comment: They could also SSH out to a custom port, like 80, if the 22 is blocked. It really depends on what the scenario is here. Why are you trying to do this, Ken? What systems are they SSHing to that you want to block? Are they internal? Or something custom across the internet?

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm not convinced that it's necessarily appropriate to migrate to SF; I haven't joined SF and am not really "plugged in" to their culture.

Answer (score -1):

You should OK to block outgoing SSH if you don't need it for anything.  Blocking outgoing requests on port 22 will not block incoming requests (because blocking is done on the destination port, which is different to the source port).

I've not played around with it much, but on some versions of iptables it should also be possible to block connections based on the userid, with a command like

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m owner -uid XXX -j DROP
```

To find the uid, you can look in the password file, with a command like

```
 grep "username" /etc/passwd | cut -f3 -d":"
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

You can block all `SSH communication` through `iptables` and allow for particular `IP ADDRESS.`

In below example,

First two rule is to allow for particular IP Address.

```
x.x.x.x - Your system IP
```

Last two rules, will block SSH connection for all IP address.

```
iptables -I INPUT -s x.x.x.x --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x --sport ssh -j ACCEPT
IPTABLES -A INPUT --dport ssh -j DROP
IPTABLES -A OUTPUT --sport ssh -j DROP
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't block "SSH communication", it just blocks port 22. If I was a user restricted this way, I'd just run an sshd server on port, say, 2222, on the target machine, and then I'd happily connect to it from the source machine with those iptables rules. As mentioned in the comments to this question, first you need to define the scenario.

Comment: For that, If your SSH port changes, Use ssh instead of 22. It means if you will change ssh port it will get it from socket example - "2222" . It will block and allow as per iptables rules when your ssh port changes. 
`iptables -I INPUT -s x.x.x.x --dport ssh -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -I OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x --sport ssh -j ACCEPT`

`IPTABLES -A INPUT --dport ssh -j DROP`

`IPTABLES -A OUTPUT --sport ssh -j DROP`

Comment: It's not that "the ssh port changes". It's that the user you want to block from using ssh can easily do that by picking some other port you (the admin) have not already blocked. So you can block ports all day long, and keeping adding ports to it, the user you want to block will just switch to a different port. And you can't block all ports...

Comment: i edited my answer, i just choose ssh instead of 22. it will automatically take ssh port from socket.

Comment: No, it won't. It will look up `ssh` in `/etc/services` and take the port number from there, which is 22. There is no "ssh port on a socket". And you haven't understood anything of what I was trying to explain.

Comment: I get your question, first of all you already know SSH work on single port. and for that you need to change `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` . After that, it will change the default port but it will not show you in `/etc/service` . But when you use command to check ip and port relation. example `netstat -tulpn`. `socket - 0.0.0.0:6969`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90300/discussion-between-bhupender-singh-and-dirkt).

Answer (score -1):

You have a different option in centos 6 and Centos 7

Many of us use `TCP wrapper`, `iptables` and `firewalld`

TCP wrapper Example

```
/etc/hosts.allow

sshd : IP-Address
```

Iptables Example

```
iptables -I INPUT -s x.x.x.x --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
IPTABLES -A INPUT --dport 22 -j DROP
IPTABLES -A OUTPUT --sport 22 -j DROP
```

then run below command

```
service iptables save
```

Firewalld Example

```
systemctl start firewalld.service
systemctl enable firewalld.service
firewall-cmd –zone=”trusted” –add-source=<external IP 1>
firewall-cmd –zone=”trusted” –add-source=<external IP 1> –permanent
firewall-cmd –zone=”trusted” –add-source=<external IP 2>
firewall-cmd –zone=”trusted” –add-source=<external IP 2> –permanent
firewall-cmd –zone=”trusted” –add-service=ssh
firewall-cmd –zone=”trusted” –add-service=ssh –permanent
firewall-cmd –zone=”trusted” –list-all
firewall-cmd –zone=public –remove-service=ssh
firewall-cmd –zone=public –remove-service=ssh –permanent
```